# Is there a way to disable the cookies that come with scraping an images link?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, web-scraping

I am scraping some phone images off of [Bell's Website](https://www.bell.ca/Mobility/Products/Samsung-Galaxy-S10-Plus?INT=MOB_mobdevpg_BTN_poplink_Mass_051016_mb_details) and the cookies seem to come with. Im not downloading the image, im simply collecting the links to the image. Im looking to see if I can disable that or somehow get the images without the cookies [I suspect I may have to download the images].

This is my code:

```
     def ImageLinkFinder():
                phoneImagesList = []

                phoneImagesListRaw = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.device-img')

                for image in phoneImagesListRaw:
                    image = image.get_attribute("src")
                    phoneImagesList.append(image)

                return phoneImagesList
```